# What should be the termination criteria for my problem with a closed loop system identification?

Tags: optimization, linear-dynamical-system

I have modelled a dynamic system which needs to be validated against test data. A closed loop system identification process is used for the validation. In this process, the time domain simulation of the model is done for initial guess of the parameters to yield a model output. Then optimization of the parameters is carried out to reduce the root mean square error(rms) between model output and test data. The optimized parameters values are supplied as the new guess values for the next iteration. In this way, the iteration process is continued until rms error is less than a predefined value(rms error<0.1 in my calculation).

But upon solving this way, the rms error decreases(upto 0.3) until certain iterations and increases then onwards. Why does this happen? I thought the rms error should stagnate if it cannot decrease further, but instead it increases. What am I doing wrong? How should the termination criteria for the system identification process be stated so that it terminates at the best but also a reliable solution?